# How would one bottom-align two divs when floated side-by-side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two boxes visible on a web page, one floating on the left and the other floating on the right. I want these boxes to align along the bottom. The problem is, there is one box whose height will change for different screen widths because it contains text and when the text wraps the height increases. The other box doesn't have any text and can be any height, but it has text above it which will change the box's y position depending on how much text wraps.

**I would like to bottom align the two boxes by changing the height of the box that contains no text, or increase the padding/margin above it.** I do not want to change the right box's height, and I want the top left text and the top of the right box to remain aligned at the top. If possible only using CSS, but a JavaScript solution would be acceptable, preferably no jQuery or other plugins.

I have defined an outer `div` with `width` set to `100%` and some `padding` so that the content on the page is inset from the edges. Inside this outer `div` is a `div` that is `float`ing `left`, `width` set to `35%`. Inside that `div` is a `div` that contains text, and a sibling to that `div` is another `div` that is the box that contains no text whose `height` is a fixed value that I can change. Then there is a box that's a child of the outer `div`, which is `float`ing `right` with `width` set to `60%`. This box will increase in `height` as the browser width decreases due to the wrapping text this box contains - I don't wish to modify its height.

```
<div id="outerDiv" style="width:100%; padding:5%;">
    <div id="leftContainer" style="float:left; width:35%;">
        <div id="topText">some text here...</div>
        <div id="bottomEmptyBox" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainerBox" style="float:right; width:60%;">
        <div id="containedText">some text here...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: The current situation]

[image: How a solution would look with increased box height]

[image: How a solution would look with increased top padding/margin]

Comment: just a question... what about setting `max-height` and `overflow:auto`?  I'm not sure if that helps in your situation or not.

Comment: Also possibly using `position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;` and `position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;` instead of floats.  If they need to stay inside parent container just give parent `position:relative;`

Comment: I could try that @GaryStorey. I just edited the question to note that I want the top left text and the top of the right box to remain aligned at the top as well.

Comment: How about setting `display:table-row` on parent div and `display:table-cell` on each child div?

Answer (score 0):

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwkggcje/2/)

This would seem to be a good base that achieves most of your objectives

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#outerDiv {
    display: table;
}
#leftContainer,
#rightContainerBox {
    display: table-cell;
}
#bottomEmptyBox {
    border:1px solid red;
}

#topText {
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#rightContainerBox {
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This almost works, it's just opposite - the big right box that has text shouldn't change in height except due to its own containing text wrapping while the small left box shouldn't have a set height.

Comment: Sorry...I don't understand. I haven't set any heights except those you gave. Anyway, it's just a starting point.

Comment: I would like the small box's height to be dynamic and increase/decrease to align to the big box's bottom. The small box's height is currently fixed to 200px in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Give parent div `display: table;` or `display:table-row` and child div `display:table-cell`

Also add height auto if necessary. Or it will take by default.

Or you can use jQuery plugin if you need much scalable.

http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/